# Navigation using Prettyfaces with dynamic id

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I have a very simple page that simply prompts the user for a name and will then create a resource with that name. When the user hits the submit button, I would like to directly navigate him to the page for the just created entity. So my page looks like this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:fieldset legend="Create new">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Name" />
            <p:inputText value="#{createBean.entity.name}" />
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Create Entity" ajax="false"
            action="#{createBean.submit}">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

The `submit` action of the `createBean` should now persist the entity. This, as a side effect, assigns a ID to the entity. And now I would like to navigate to this entity.

```
public void submit() {
    /* Persist entity, entity.getId() will now
       return a meaningful value. */

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler handler = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

    // How could I pass the ID?
    handler.handleNavigation(context, null, "pretty:entity-detail");
}
```

The mapping of `entity-detail` looks like this:

```
<url-mapping id="entity">
    <pattern value="/entities" />
    <view-id value="/views/entity/list.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping parentId="entity" id="entity-detail">
    <pattern value="/view/#{id}" />
    <view-id value="/views/entity/entityDetail.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

For the record: using Apache MyFaces 2.1.5 and PrettyFaces 3.3.2.

Comment: Could you post the mapping "entity-detail" please?

Comment: Ah, sure. Don't know how I could manage to forget that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using named path parameters in your mapping. In this case you can simply return the viewId from the action method and append a corresponding query parameter.

```
public String submit() {

    /* Persist entity, entity.getId() will now
       return a meaningful value. */

    long id = ....

    return "/views/entity/entityDetail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id=" + id;

}
```

For EL-injected parameters the process is a bit different. See [this chapter](http://ocpsoft.com/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.2/en-US/html/navigation.html#navigation.actions) of the documentation for details.